# Angular infinite scrolling strategy with IntersectionObserver

Tags: html, angular, infinite-scroll, angular-components, intersection-observer

I've been reading a lot about infinite scrolling strategies as I need to implement this functionality in my component. However, there seems to exist a lot of different approaches and the examples I've seen are not the most straight forward and easy to understand.

To put it briefly, this component consists of 3 mat-tabs (each represent a different order status), and inside each one of these there is a list of order components for that corresponding order status.

The smart parent component looks something like:

```
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight animationDuration="400ms">
    <mat-tab>
        <app-orders-list
            [orders]="loadedPendingOrders"
            [timelines]="pendingOrderTimelines"
            [isDeliverySlotsActive]="isDeliverySlotsActive"
            [searchTerm]="searchTerm"
        ></app-orders-list>
    </mat-tab>
    ...
    /* more tabs */
</mat-tab-group>
```

And the child app-orders-list looks like this (each section contains orders):

```
<div class="list-container" [ngClass]="{section: isDeliverySlotsActive === false}">
     <div [ngClass]="{section: isDeliverySlotsActive === true}" *ngFor="let date of timelines">
        <app-orders-list-section
            [orders]="orders"
            [timeline]="date"
            [isDeliverySlotsActive]="isDeliverySlotsActive"
            [searchTerm]="searchTerm"
        ></app-orders-list-section>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I reach the bottom of this list on a scroll down event, I need to load more orders from the API and present them accordingly.

Given this architecture, what strategy do you recommend for infinite scrolling? I'm mainly looking for something like a directive that implements the IntersectionObserver API and triggers an event when the bottom of the list is reached.

I'm not interested in solutions that use ngx-infinite-scrolling.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why you are not want to go with ngx-infinite-scrolling

Comment: I don't want to depend on an external library. I know it can be done without it and also my supervisor prefers it that way (sentinel element + IntersectionObserver).

Comment: Yes You can go with intercetion-observer api.. use this inside directive and apply directive at root element and all your infinite scrolling logic will work. directive return you true or false if your are in bottom of page or not and based on this value, you will call api . BTW your api is also fully paginated then it will be easy for you too.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. And yes, the API is paginated :) But as a junior dev and angular noob I need some code examples of this but I can't find ones that are simple enough for me.

Comment: here you need to do two part.. Part 1 : First detect bottom of page. Part 2 : Then call api based on required data with correct page number.

Comment: do you done any code or do you want to do it from scratch and also wants to learn it more?

Comment: Right now i'm looking for some directive code to detect bottom of list with trigger event using the IntersectionObserver (as long as I get this I think I can do the rest). I want to learn more about it. I have the API communication setup and right now i'm getting only one page of data in ngOnInit.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xga6ry?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html here is demo. tell me part you are not getting.

Comment: https://blog.bitsrc.io/angular-maximizing-performance-with-the-intersection-observer-api-23d81312f178

Comment: @GaurangDhorda That is exactly what I want sir but the event is not triggering :( which component should I wrap with <app-infinite-scroll>?

Comment: @ManuelBrás its working fine at my side https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xga6ry?file=src%2Fapp%2Finfinite-scroll%2Finfinite-scroll.component.html

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Yes your example is working sir, but I don't know how to apply in my project.

Comment: @ManuelBrás you need to put all of your code inside `<app-infinite-scroll> --- </app-infinite-scroll>` and once, you reach bottom of page, onScroll() method gets called, and now, you can call your next pagination api.

Comment: @ManuelBrás which part are you not getting properly ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda It's not working when I wrap the parent smart component `app-orders`, and also not working if I wrap `app-orders-list` component. However it does seem to work when the list does not reach the bottom (e.g. list ends in the middle of screen and the `onScroll()` is triggered)

Comment: @GaurangDhorda This [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67273415/15822615) is working for me.

Comment: @ManuelBrás try every thing inside one div , like `<app-infinite-scroll> <div> --- your all component code goes here ---- </div> </app-infinite-scroll>`, may be this works for your. :) happy learning there is only one parent div inside app-infinite-scroll component,